How do I remove the trailing space from elements that end with a newline?
I want to nest the text in certain HTML tags for clarity while editing, such that the opening tag, text, and closing tag each occupy their own line, like so:


<p>
  Lorem ipsum.
</p>



When this element is rendered, no space character is added to the front of the text; however, a space is added to the end of the text (as is visible when highlighted). I would like to remove this trailing space. Is there a simple, low-hack solution to get the browser to treat the ending newline like the starting newline instead of adding a space?
I imagine most people would just put up with this behavior or use a different formatting convention, but with how common it is to find trailing spaces on websites, I was curious if anyone had a solution.

Does this behaviour occur only in Firefox?

I tried it with <pre> and that seems to strip the trailing whitespace. However it also adds the indentation, which is probably not what you want.

@JaromandaX That may be so. I was using Firefox v129 when I got the trailing space, and I do not get a trailing space with the provided snippet with Chrome v127.

@SSS yes, that was my observation - not sure if either browser breaks some specification regarding this behaviour or if this falls under "unspecified" behaviour.

@GRASBOCK I got the same result. And yes, I don't want the indentation to be rendered either, since I'm going for visual clarity in my editor.

It's like the rendering difference in browser. If you connect it using the annotation <!----> in html, you can clear the blank. However, it seem like adding unnecessary annotation codes to make a line-break in the code.
